# Reload Keystore without needing to restart Server

Tags: java, keystore

I've been looking for a solution but haven't found anything, Is it possible to reload the java keystore without restarting JVM.

Comment: Are you loading the Keystore yourself in the first place or is the JVM loading it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you mean, but you can interact with (create, load, update) a Java keystore via the KeyStore class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html

Example of loading a keystore:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ks.load(new FileInputStream("newKeyStoreFileName.jks"), pwdArray);
```

Comment: If I add cert to my application. Right now I need to restart Server, to make that cert works. Instead without restarting my server. I wanted my cert to work.